# Create simple Card layout android

Tags: android, layout, android-cardview

I want to create a simple card layout like this image

[image]

this is my layout

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:fresco="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="200dp"
        android:layout_margin="3dp"
        android:id="@+id/offer_card">

        <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="right">

            <LinearLayout
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1.5">

                <RelativeLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_weight="0.3">
                    <com.facebook.drawee.view.SimpleDraweeView
                        android:id="@+id/img_offer"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                        fresco:placeholderImage="@drawable/backgrondlayout2"
                        fresco:actualImageScaleType="centerCrop" />

                    <com.facebook.drawee.view.SimpleDraweeView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"

                        android:id="@+id/img_logo"
                        android:layout_margin="10dp"
                        fresco:placeholderImage="@drawable/ic_launcher"
                        fresco:actualImageScaleType="centerCrop" />


                    <TextView
                        android:text="Title"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_below="@+id/img_logo"
                        android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/img_logo"
                        android:id="@+id/txt_name"
                        android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Large"
                        android:textColor="@color/white" />

                </RelativeLayout>

            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:padding="4dp"
                android:layout_weight="1">

                <TextView
                    android:text="TitleOfOffer is here sgffs"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:id="@+id/txt_Title"
                    android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Title"
                    android:fontFamily="sans-serif-medium"
                    android:layout_weight="0.2"
                    android:textAlignment="textEnd" />

                <TextView
                    android:text="this is a simple discription with losts of text sjdun a;daiwn adwi"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:id="@+id/txt_discription"
                    android:layout_weight="0.2"
                    android:textAlignment="textEnd" />

                <ImageView
                    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                    android:src="@android:drawable/divider_horizontal_textfield"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:scaleType="fitXY"
                    android:paddingBottom="1dp"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="10dp" />
                <TextView
                    android:text="Date"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:id="@+id/txt_Date"
                    android:textAlignment="textEnd"
                    android:drawableRight="@drawable/ic_directions_black_24dp" />

                <TextView
                    android:text="Distance"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:id="@+id/txt_distance"
                    android:textAlignment="textEnd"
                    android:drawableRight="@drawable/ic_settings_black_24dp"
                    android:hapticFeedbackEnabled="false"
                    android:layoutDirection="rtl" />

            </LinearLayout>

        </LinearLayout>
    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
</LinearLayout>
```

and this is result

[image]

well as you can see left image highly is depended in texts on right. How can I reform this layout and make it stable, because by changing in texts the images will move, Also I have added one image (`img_logo`) which does not appear at all.Can you please help me find a good solution to reform my layout?
thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To keep the layout ratio in your case you could use this XML attributes `android:ellipsize` and `android:maxLines` on the TextView.

TextView example:

```
<TextView android:id="@+id/txt_discription"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
    android:ellipsize="end"
    android:maxLines="2"
    tools:text="This is a simple discription with losts of text lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua."
    />
```

This is a simple example of a CardView into XML layout file using the previous TextView:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/card_view"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="200dp"
    android:layout_margin="8dp"
    card_view:cardCornerRadius="4dp"
    >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/card_background_image"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop"
        tools:src="@android:mipmap/sym_def_app_icon"
        />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical" 
        android:background="@android:drawable/screen_background_dark_transparent"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        android:padding="16dp"
        >
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/card_title"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:paddingTop="8dp"
            android:paddingBottom="8dp"
            android:textAllCaps="true"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
            android:ellipsize="end"
            android:maxLines="1"
            tools:text="Cart title"
            />

        <TextView android:id="@+id/txt_discription"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
            android:ellipsize="end"
            android:maxLines="2"
            tools:text="this is a simple discription with losts of text lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua."
            />

    </LinearLayout>
</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: thanks very much,Do you have any simple card like it and share its xml so I can find out what other ways is possible to create such a this layouts

Comment: @MajidHojati I hope the CardView example can helps.

Answer (score 1):

I made a little example of `ListView` and `CardView`. https://github.com/AndroidAppNotes/ListView-and-CardView
[image: ListView-and-CardView]

Comment: My pleasure :-)